# Is it possible to setup vim to use vimtex for Rmd files?

Tags: filetype-tex, plugin-vimtex

I need to write Rmd files, but I can't imagine life without vimtex. Is there a way that I can use vimtex with Rmd files? Ideally, I would also like to keep the syntax highlighting that I have for Rmd files (via https://github.com/vim-pandoc/vim-rmarkdown).

**Edit**: In response to a comment by **@filbranden**, here is [useful post that provides more information on Rmarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40563479/relationship-between-r-markdown-knitr-pandoc-and-bookdown). Because the files are rendered using pandoc, one can mix R code with standard markdown with LaTeX.

As a simple example, an Rmarkdown file might contain code that looks like this:

```
# My document header
Here is an **emphasis**. Now here's some LaTeX:

\begin{align}
    \hat{\beta} = \hat{\alpha}^{3} + \epsilon.
\end{align}
```

In a `.tex` document I could use vimtex features, such as `cse` inside the `align` environment to toggle it to an `align*` environment. That's just one of many many features of vimtex that I would like to be able to use in Rmd.

**@Karl Yngve Lervåg** is the creator of vimtex, so if he doesn't know of a solution then that's not a great sign for there being one...

Is it a bad idea to "trick" vim into thinking that an Rmd is a Tex file?
Then presumably I could use vimtex features?
The downside is that the syntax highlighting would be messed up.

Comment: I don't have much experience with RMarkdown and I don't really use TeX that often... But aren't Markdown and TeX completely separate languages? How would vimtex help editing a Markdown file? I'm guessing it's maybe some extension to typeset math formulas in Markdown (or specifically RMarkdown), but I think it would be helpful if your question would spell out more clearly what kind of support you're expecting from vimtex on RMarkdown.

Comment: I don't know a good solution to this, but at least there are some relevant threads in the vimtex issues: see [#1706](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues/1706) and [#1729](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues/1729).

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg could I do something like you suggest here: https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues/1729#issuecomment-653228007. "The bundled ftplugin/rnoweb.vim already does runtime! ftplugin/tex.vim and thus loads vimtex. " Maybe I can make .Rmd files do that as well?

Comment: You might want to consider filing an issue about it under vim-pandoc or vim-rmarkdown... If TeX snippets are part of the syntax, integration with vimtex (or perhaps similar/equivalent key mappings) might be something they might want to add first class support for.

Comment: I might consider to make changes to improve this type of secondary filetype support, but if so, I really _need_ help. What I mean: I am no expert in R markdown at all, and so I need clear and consise feature requests with good examples.

Comment: I think @filbranden's comment is very good: it would be best if integration is initiated from e.g. vim-pandoc or vim-markdown (or related plugins).

Comment: When I have worked with .Rnw files in the past, I found that vimtex worked well. I had to hack together an appropriate .latexmkrc to make continuous compilation (\ll) work, but that wasn't too hard. I am just trying to get vimtex to _load_ in .Rmd files the same as in .Rnw files. I'm hesitant to open an issue because I'm not really sure what I am asking for here. In particular, I don't know enough about vim to understand which of the various plugins I am using is doing what.

Comment: Here's a question that's a bit more specific and would help me clear up my confusion. Suppose I open a .Rmd. `set ft` returns `filetype=rmd`. If I do `set ft=tex` I am able to use vimtex features and the syntax highlighting changes. However, I am also able to use features from the plugin NVim-R, which loads for .rmd files. So what controls the order in which different plugins load? And is it correct that they do not "unload" if the filetype is changed later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I found a reasonable solution.
I expect this is not a "good" solution, so would appreciate any thoughts as to how it could go wrong, and how to strengthen it.

To get `vimtex` features to load, I simply put this in `ftplugin/rmd.vim`:

```
set filetype=tex
```

That's it --- now all of the `vimtex` bindings and motions appear to load when I open an `rmd.vim` file. Many of the `vimtex` features obviously won't work correctly with `.rmd` files, such as the ones that involve compiling and expect a `.tex` document. However, the `NVim-R` plugin provides good compilation/viewing solutions for `.rmd`, and I am still able to use that after `set filetype=tex`, presumably because they have already been loaded.

A major source of confusion for me was that there is a difference in syntax highlighting behavior between calling `:set filetype=tex` manually after opening a file, and putting `set filetype=tex` in `ftplugin/rmd.vim`. Changing the filetype manually also changes the syntax highlighting, but changing the filetype inside the `ftplugin` script preserves the `.rmd` syntax highlighting. I think this is because scripts in `syntax` are called after those in `ftplugin`, but I'm not sure.

The upshot is that if you put the `filetype` call into `ftplugin`, you can both load `vimtex` features and preserve `rmd` syntax highlighting --- which is what I wanted.