# Using VimTex "in_mathzone()" in .tid files

Tags: plugin-ultisnips, plugin-vimtex

I am writing files with the extension ".tid" for a piece of software called [TiddlyWiki](https://tiddlywiki.com/) whose syntax is pretty similar to that of markdown. In these files, I want to be able to write down latex and I used to use UltiSnips and vimtex for this; the problem is that I can't seem to get the traditional `context "math()"` to work.

I have read [this](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues/1937) page and while it gives some example code that supposedly worked, I have tried *exactly* that and it hasn't worked. I also read [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/28178/is-it-possible-to-setup-vim-to-use-vimtex-for-rmd-files) page but I want to not have to declare the filetype as `tex` because I want to have separate snippets files for `.tid` and `.tex` files.

Here is a minimal working example:

I have a file called "tid.snippets" with the contents:

```
global !p
def math():
    return vim.eval('vimtex#syntax#in_mathzone()') == '1'
endglobal

context "math()"
snippet vec "Vector" iA
\frac{${1:numer}}{${2:denom}}${0}
endsnippet

snippet happy "Happy" iA
$1 is such a happy person!
$0
endsnippet
```

In addition, I have added the following line to my `.vimrc` in order to make it recognise `.tid` files:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.tid setfiletype tid
```

When I create a new file `example.tid`, I type `happy` and it expands the snippet as expected. When I type `$  $` and put my cursor inside the $s and type `vec`, nothing happens. If I change the filetype to `tex` by giving Vim the command `:set filetype=tex` then it all works...

Can someone help?

Comment: IIRC the math zone detection is based on the syntax. You would probably need to port the correct syntax definitions for tiddlywiki files

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Could you elaborate at all? Why is it that people say it can "just work" using Markdown files but not in this case? They don't have similar syntax... How would I "port" the syntax definitions in the way you suggest?

Comment: I dont know about all the markdown stuff. The thing is that typically that math context relies on detecting the presence of specific syntax groups which won’t exist without loading the tex syntax. If you could discover the relevant ones, you could add rules to `~/.vim/syntax/tid.vim` to include tex syntax in the right places, and that might help… honestly, you’re better off asking the vimtex folks (the maintainer drops by here occasionally, perhaps they can help).